# Warning: no files found matching when I make a building wheel (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, python-wheel

When I make a building wheel, I get these warnings. Are these ignorable or any idea about these warnings?

`warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.lib' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'tensorflow/include/tensorflow'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/Eigen'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/external'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'tensorflow/include/google'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/third_party'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/unsupported'`

Comment: what are you trying to do ? installing TF?

Comment: @Engine Yes. Are those critical directories?

Comment: how  are you installing it, what's your OS ?

Comment: @Engine It's ubuntu 16.03 LTS, sorry for late answer.

Comment: I have the same issue, then I get "___.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." when I try to install it.

Comment: Any solution to this issue?

Comment: I had the same issue with tf 2.4, cuda 11.2, cudnn 8.1.1, mint cinnamon 20.1. I was following the 2.3 guide https://gist.github.com/kmhofmann/e368a2ebba05f807fa1a90b3bf9a1e03

Comment: My warnings were similar though a little different: Sun 21 Mar 2021 07:57:36 PM CDT : === Building wheel
warning: no files found matching 'README'
warning: no files found matching '*.pyd' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.pyi' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.pd' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.dylib' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.lib' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.csv' under directory '*'
...

Comment: After installing the wheel with the warnings, importing tensorflow gave the following error messages: >>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
...    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  ...
ImportError: cannot import name 'function_pb2' from 'tensorflow.core.framework' (unknown location)

Comment: The warning turned out to be warnings. The install seems to work. My issue was running python from the build directory. It worked after going to home as per the advice from the following link: https://gitmemory.com/issue/tensorflow/tensorflow/40182/645993088

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the wheel and exiting the build directory.
Sometimes warnings are only warnings.

My install worked despite similar warnings, though
I had to move out of the build directory
to successfully import tensorflow in python.

Trying to import tensorflow while still in the build directory gave the following error:

```
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 24 2021, 21:46:12) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "~/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "~/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'function_pb2' from 'tensorflow.core.framework' (unknown location)
```

I thank Saifullah3396 at gitmeory for helping with that problem.

The following are the warnings that I received for the wheel that seems to work.

```
Sun 21 Mar 2021 07:57:36 PM CDT : === Building wheel
warning: no files found matching 'README'
warning: no files found matching '*.pyd' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.pyi' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.pd' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.dylib' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.lib' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.csv' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'tensorflow/include/tensorflow'
warning: no files found matching '*.proto' under directory 'tensorflow/include/tensorflow'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/third_party'
Sun 21 Mar 2021 07:58:30 PM CDT : === Output wheel file is in: /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```